# Find the values of $\alpha$ for which the integral $\int_0^1(-\ln x)^\alpha$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Find the values of $\alpha$ for which the integral $\int_0^1(-\ln x)^\alpha$ converges.

My thoughts:

For $\alpha>0: 0$ is a the problematic point and for $\alpha<0: 1$ is a the problematic point

$(-\ln x)^\alpha$ is a positive function for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

So I tried the comparison tests, substitute $x=e^t$ and integrating by parts, but couldn't solve it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Come to terms with the idea that the integral doesn't converge for _all_ $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Find the correct condition on $\alpha$ for convergence.

Comment: That said, you have correctly identified the points you need to look at. Perhaps $x = e^{-t}$ is a better substitution than $x = e^t$.

Comment: This is not true for all $\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enforcing the substitution $x=e^{-t}$,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(-\log t\right)^{\alpha}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{\alpha}e^{-x}\,dx =\Gamma(\alpha+1)$$
holds for any $\color{red}{\alpha > -1}$, since we have to deal only with the possible singularity of $x^{\alpha}e^{-x}\sim x^{\alpha}$ at the origin. If $\alpha\geq 0$ there is no singularity at all, and if $\alpha\in(-1,0)$ such singularity is integrable. If $\alpha\leq -1$ it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't study about Singular Integral. Any chance for an alternative proof?

Comment: @Itay4: I am not involving any *singular integral*, I am just recalling the well-known statement according to $x^\alpha$ is integrable over $(0,1)$ iff $\alpha >-1$.